# publish SSTP VPN through reverse proxy?

Tags: windows-server-2016, reverse-proxy, sstp

Good day Everyone

I have setup a microsoft web application proxy to reverse proxy a couple of sites.
I would like to know if anyone know if it is possible to publish our sstp vpn though the WAP? this will obviously not be http/s but rather just an fqdn like vpn.corp.com

thank you

regards

Comment: But if it's "not HTTP/S", then how do you expect a HTTP reverse proxy to proxy it?

Comment: Fair enough, is there a way to reverse proxy non HTTP/S traffic?